# UITableView top padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, tableview

As shown in the screenshot below my UITableView has a large amount of padding at the top which shows above my header cell. I have been though all the settings and searched the internet for hours but found know mention of this top padding and how to remove it on plain table (this is not a grouped style table).

Can anyone tell me how to remove this padding so the header cell is at the top of the table view.

[image]

Comment: Your table view might be adding additional content insets to account for the height of the navigation bar, if it is the bottom-most subview in your view controller's view.

Comment: Thanks, I do not really understand what that means but I tried adding something above my UITableView in the main view which seemed to fix the problem but now the header is hidden and can only be seen by scrolling down